# Reloading data in tableView for invisible sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Then I get json update I reload my tableView, but I have tableView with collectionView inside it and I have little lag in visible cell at the moment of reload. I want to reload only invisible cell of tableView. But there is no 'visibleSections' method like 'visibleCells'.

I get all visible sections

```
 NSArray *visibleSections = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]valueForKey:@"section"];
```

Not I want get all sections, then remove all visibleSections and reload this new array. But I can not find the way to get all sections. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of these methods:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
- (void)reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
```

**Edit**

When you try to get the indexPaths of all invisible cells, you could try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *invisibleCells = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [tabsTableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < [tabsTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; n++) {
        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [tabsTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
            if ([indexPath section] == i && [indexPath row] == n) {
                goto nextIteration;
            }
        }
        
        [invisibleCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:n inSection:i]];
            
    nextIteration:;
    }
}
```

More important is why you would like to do that?! Due `UITableViewCell`s get reused, they won't be updatable. When the cell is "invisible", it changes its content and is used at a different position within the visible cells. This is how `UITableView` works.

You will (also currently) use this method to set the content of the cell:

```
- (void)tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_cellID];
    
    if (!cell) {
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cellTemplate" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    
    // configure cell content here
}
```

When the cell get's reused, this method gets called and you create the cell only if `UITableView` does not reuse an invisible cell. If it does, you change the content.

So there is no need to reload invisible cells and it's impossible. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_29):

> **Return Value**
>
> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

Comment: How can I get invisible sections in array/set?